# How to create a double vaulted ceiling

Tags: mesh

So I understand how to make a vaulted ceiling from this:
[How to create an arch (vault) that is curved inside?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129936/how-to-create-an-arch-vault-that-is-curved-inside)

But I am wondering how I would trim the individual triangles that make the vault up with more vaults like pic related? Any help would be appreciated [image: Vaulted Ceiling]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it this way:

- Create a 16/8 vertex UV sphere, cut it in half:

[image]

- Scale 1 edge out of 2, constrain on X and Y:

[image]

- Give your object a *Boolean* modifier with a cube as *Object*:

[image]

- Cut this vertical edge with the knife:

[image]

- Cut a hole, duplicate the stained glass window and shift it on the right:

[image]

- Create a bridge between the window and the hole:

[image]

- Only keep 1/8th of the whole shape and mirror it:

[image]

- Array the shape with an *Object Offset*:

[image]

- You have your basis shape (view from the bottom):

[image]

Comment: Wow, cool - I would have never figured that out. I just looked at the reference and actually didn't know how it was built in detail. The only thing that bothers me while trying to rebuild your solution: no matter how much more or less I scale in the edges of the sphere in the beginning, I never get it to the point where the cube cuts the "windows" so far in that the top has these three vertices and still keeps the corners at the bottom...

Comment: To be honest I almost gave up as it seemed rather complicated, until I found how to begin (with a sphere that needs 1 edge out of 2 to be scaled). I wonder how these architects had so crazy ideas. I'm not sure it's very important to have the 3 vertices, you can still create them afterwards. I've just released a tutorial on this vault on my channel btw, if it helps.

Comment: I'll try to look at the tutorial... going further I get more problems. The window in the middle is much too large when I duplicate it and move it over, it exceeds the overall shape by far. It looks all so different in your screenshots although I seem to be doing exactly what you explain there. And I'm no beginner at Blender modelling.

Comment: Yes it needs a bit of corrections afterwards, like narrowing the window, or moving the pillars a bit, not a lot though

Comment: I watched the tutorial, okay that explains a lot... you scaled it much more in than it appears in the screenshot and the cube isn't going down to the bottom of the sphere, it sits higher... that makes much more of a difference than I thought.