# How to cut a face based on the edge nearby? (Vaults)

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to model for my school a very specific arch, and I have to do an animation to explain how it works. As you can see in this picture : [image]

Here's what the arch looks like. Modeling it separately is easy but I want to be able to join those individual arches into one and be able to select each face. Here is an example :[image]

I would like to cut the face selected into two and cut where the other arch come through. I want to delete what is below because I don't need it. I tried to boolean each of them but it's junky and doesn't work.

Do you have a solution? Thank you!

Léo Thiery

Comment: Related: [How to create a Gothic Vault?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/129936/78972)

Answer (score 6):

You should better use the *Mirror* modifier with the *Bisect* option enabled (here on Y) and an empty as *Mirror Object*:

[image]

Now if you rotate the empty on Z (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>30</kbd> for example) and move it, you can achieve what you're trying to:

[image]

But you can also select one of your meshes, go into the *Face panel > Intersect (Knife)*:

[image]

It will create an edge all along the intersection, now you can select the faces and remove them:

[image]

Comment: Wow ! I'm surprised of how fast you answered, with such an easy and well explained solution. Thank you very much it will for sure help me !

Comment: you are welcome, maybe choose the second solution as your meshes are ready

Comment: Snuck in before me again! :)  I know _you_ get this, but just for OP...  3 consecutive bisecting _Mirrors_, the first 2 through origin Empties rotated by 30 and 60, will take you all the way from 1 arch to a 6-way vault. The internal math for bisecting mirrors is much cleaner and simpler (therefore more accurate?)  than 'Intersect > Knife', so personally I would prefer that?

Comment: I agree, it would be much cleaner, but for the animation I sadly have to keep what is under the arch, to show their intersection. With the mirror workflow I dont have those intersections.